# Is there a way to create an in-memory mongo server in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, integration-testing

I want to write an integration test for my service and am trying to set up an in-memory mongodb instance to write and read from within the integration tests.

I have found the exact same question for JS, [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607732/in-memory-mongodb-for-test), where the answer suggests to use MongoMemoryServer available in JS.

Is there an equivalent library or construct in the MongoJavaDriver?

Comment: https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo

Comment: Maybe you are interested https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo

Comment: Also, you could have a local mongod running with the in-memory engine.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/